# Java 7 Update 55.pkg can't be installed because its digital signature is invalid

Tags: macos, java, pkg, signature

I'm trying to install Java in order to use the Safari plugin. The "missing plugin" functionality redirects me to [the Java download page](https://www.java.com/en/download/mac_download.jsp), where I downloaded a file named `jre-7u55-macosx-x64.dmg`, which contains `Java 7 Update 55.pkg`.

Now, when I try to run the installer, I get the following error message:

> **Java 7 Update 55.pkg can't be installed because its digital signature is invalid.**
>   The package may have been corrupted or tampered with. Get a new copy of the package and try again.

I'm not sure what to do here. I do need to install the plugin unfortunately. :-)

I'm running OS X 10.9.2 (up to date, as far as I can tell from the App Store) on a mid 2009 mbp, in case that makes any difference.

Comment: Download it again, I've had such thing an ISO was corrupt. After redownloading it worked. It might help you too.